# Framework for documentation: java rest api

Tags: java, api, document-management, markdown

I have a project in java, with APIs in REST. I wanted to create a wiki with documentation (markdown) on the APIs. First phase only the specifications, then also include a way to test the API (API console / explorer). These are APIs with OpenID (OAUTH) authentication, with tokens.

Any suggestion of framework or cloud service that will provide this type of service?

Thank you.

Comment: Try Swagger. I think you should have asked it on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

For documenting your RESTful api, you can use swagger. You can use annotation in your code and add dependency for swagger and you can easily see the documentation and test it from there as well.

You can also provide the documentation in json or yml format and it supports all major languages.

You can visit site- [swagger.io](https://swagger.io/) for more information.